# Custom table in Uniselector in Kentico

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

I have been using Kentico without issue for a while until today, here is my issue

I want to use Custom table in uniselector.

How I came into the issue was, I need to use Custom Form Controls, like in SiteManager->Users Advanced filter.
We have Add Roles which opens a popup and it shows list of all roles.

This webpart uses Uniselector

```
<cms:CMSUpdatePanel ID="pnlUpdate" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <cms:UniSelector ObjectType="cms.role" SelectionMode="MultipleTextBox"
            OrderBy="RoleDisplayName" ResourcePrefix="roleselect" runat="server"
            ID="usRoles" ShortID="s" AllowEditTextBox="true" AddGlobalObjectSuffix="true" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</cms:CMSUpdatePanel>
```

Now if I use

```
ObjectType="cms.role"
```

it works fine because it is system table

now if I use

```
ObjectType="customtable.country"
```

This will not work

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since version 7 you can use:

```
ObjectType="customtableitem.namespace.customtable"
```

it would be

```
ObjectType="customtableitem.customtable.SampleTable"
```

for Sample custom table (from Corporate sample site).

Feel free to contact me if you have any other questions.

Comment: We will give it a try, if it's that easy, it will be really amazing :)

Comment: Hi rocky,I tried your solution it's really good and working fine. 
May I know how to set iObjectType.DisplayNameColumn , its  taking ItemGUID by default and I want to set another column name on iObjectType.DisplayNameColumn.

Comment: Hi, set DisplayNameFormat="{%DisplayNameColumn%}".

Comment: I found solution by just passed
AdditionalSearchColumns="DisplayNameColumn". it add OR condition with existing search condition.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, UniSelector requires Kentico object types by design and it does not work for custom tables.

However, there are basically three possible workarounds:

1. You can develop custom form control instead of using UniSelector -> [Developer's Guide - Developing form controls](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?developing_form_controls.htm)
2. Use built-in **Drop-down list** control
3. Modify **UniSelector** form control - you will load your DataSet in LoadObjects() method in file ~\CMSAdminControls\UI\UniSelector\UniSelector.ascx.cs

Comment: Hi Filip, 
Thanks for the update.
We did it using 1 and 3 points and it does what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

we have changed uniselector.ascx, keeping in mind that kentico can overwrite it when it gets updated
 use this CMSAdminControls

I use this approach and get success 
Created new pages as

1. CustomUniSelector.ascx
2. CustomSelectionDialog.ascx

Change method Loadobject as give
url ~/CMSAdminControls/Mycustomcontrol/CustomSelectionDialog.aspx

than change LoadControls() method in CustomSelectionDialog.ascx.cs

CMSObjectHelper.GetObject() method not get data from custom table so added new method for fetching data from custom table